# Analysis Tier exam problem: Show that $f\equiv0$

Tags: real-analysis

So I have this problem in real analysis and I am unsure if this is a sufficient answer.

The problem:

Suppose that $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function on $[0,1]$ with $$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)(x^n+x^{n+2})dx$$
for all $n=0,1,2,...$. Show that $f\equiv0$.

My Solution so far:

Given that $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function on $[0,1]$ and $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)(x^n+x^{n+2})dx$,

$$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx-\int_{0}^{1}f(x)(x^n+x^{n+2})dx=0$$
$$\int_{0}^{1}[f(x)-f(x)(x^{n}+x^{n+2})]=0$$
$$\int_{0}^{1}[f(x)(1-x^{n}-x^{n+2})]=0$$ for all $n=0,1,2,...$

Since if for some function $\int_{0}^{a}g(x)=0$ then this implies $g(x)=0$

Therefore $$f(x)(1-x^n-x^{n+2})=0$$ implies that either $f(x)=0$ or $(1-x^n-x^{n+2})=0$

Suppose $(1-x^n-x^{n+2})=0$ for all $n=0,1,2,...$
If $n=0$ then $1-x^0-x^{0+2}=0$ which implies $x^2=0$ and therefore $x=0$. But if $x=0$ then $(1-x^n-x^{n+2})=1\neq 0$. Therefore $f(x)=0$ and thus $f\equiv0$

Comment: You should proof your last claim for each value of $n$ not only for n=0

Comment: "Since if for some function $\int_0^a g(x)dx=0$ then this implies $g(x)=0$" - This is not true, for example $\int_0^1 (x-0.5) dx=0$

Comment: $\int_{0}^{1}g(t)dt=0 \iff g(t)=0$ is valid if $g$ is has a constant sign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument goes wrong from where you said "if for some function $\int_0^a g(x)=0$ then this implies $g(x)=0$". I'm not sure what you really meant, but $\int_0^a g(x)\mathrm dx =0$ for a single $a$ does not mean $g(x)=0$ because the linear functional $g\mapsto\int_0^a g $ has a kernel of codimension at most $1$. If we knew that $g$ is either non-negative or non-positive, then $\int_0^1 g(x)=0$ would be equivalent to $g(x) = 0$, but this is clearly not the case of ours. It is true that $\int_0^a g(x)\mathrm dx =0$ for every $0<a<1$ implies $g(x)=0$ (a.e.), however, your argument does not seem to be using this principle. So your answer is not giving a valid reasoning ...

Here's one of the approaches. We find that 
$$
\int_0^1 f(x) \mathrm dx =\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1 f(x)x^n(1+x^2) \mathrm dx =0
$$ by Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem. This gives
$$
 \int_0^1 f(x)x^n(1+x^2) \mathrm dx =0, \quad n\ge 0,
$$ which implies
$$
\int_0^1 f(x)p(x)(1+x^2) \mathrm dx =0
$$ for every polynomial $p:[0,1]\to \Bbb C$. By Weierstrass's approximation theorem, there is a polynomial sequence $p_n(x)$ uniformly converging to $f(x)$. Hence, we have
$$
\int_0^1 \left(f(x)\right)^2(1+x^2) \mathrm dx =\int_0^1 f(x)p_n(x)(1+x^2) \mathrm dx=0,
$$ which, by the non-negativity of the integrand, implies that $(f(x))^2(1+x^2) =0$ for every $x$. This gives $f(x) =0$ for every $x$ as wanted.

Comment: Oh whoops, I goofed. I see what you mean.